# Force RTL interface orientation or let the user decide?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, language

If you've set a language on your operating system that defaults to right-to-left interface orientation, is there any reason that you'd like to set it to left-to-right anyway? Because you might already be used to it that some applications don't support RTL?

Or asked differently: Does it make sense to add a RTL/LTR setting so that the user can decide? Or should you just force RTL interface orientation when the language is e.g. set to Arabic?

Comment: On my computer at work I have it set to English not because I want it, but because IT "forced" me to. They have the same orientation, but who knows who else in the world have had it less luckily than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Reasons one may want to force LTR even though their default language is RTL:

- Because you might already be used to it that some applications don't support RTL.
- Because you are developing software and want to see how it behaves under LTR.

> Does it make sense to add a RTL/LTR setting so that the user can
>   decide?

Add where?? In your application? Just make your application work well under LTR and RTL and the problem won't exist!

> Or should you just force RTL interface orientation when the language
>   is e.g. set to Arabic?

Yes, and get it right so the User doesn't seek alternatives such as forcing the display to LTR.